# SPO Workflow life limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, limitations

For how long can a Sharepoint Online workflow be paused without it being terminated?

Or, even if it's not in a paused state, for how long can a workflow consecutively run?

I've been asked to create an automated reminder for a specific list every quarter, although a simple task, I'm unsure on if it will work or get killed by a Microsoft service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking with Microsoft Support they said it could run indefinitely but as soon as I requested documentation to support their information, they threw me off to a [150 page html "All About Approval Workflows"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-60C865DF-3F10-4AA2-8331-60B736A5E3D5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) which didn't really help at all.

Comment: +½ (or more) for the informative value, +½ for the laughs of "they threw me off to a 150 page html".